# error executing Head First EJB first example

Tags: java, ejb

I am following Head First EJB. I know it has EJB 2.0 which is old as now EJB 3.1 is in. But I consider Head first book a good book for learning for amateurs like us.

I am using J2ee 1.3.1 RI and jdk 1.4. I ran the "deploy" tool to deploy by EJB and now I have a ejb client JAVA program given below:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import javax.rmi.*;
import headfirst.*;
import javax.ejb.*;

import java.util.*;

public class AdviceClient {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new AdviceClient().go();
    }

    public void go(){
        try{

            Properties props=new Properties();
            props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
            //props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
            //env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
            //props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
            props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"rmi://localhost:1050"); 
            //props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url","rmi://localhost:1099");

            Context ic = new InitialContext(props);
            Object o = ic.lookup("Advisor");

            AdviceHome home = (AdviceHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(o,AdviceHome.class);

            Advice advisor = home.create();
            System.out.println(advisor.getAdvice());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}






Following the book, I compiled the program. The "Properties" part is something not mentioned in the example. I got it from some other examples on the web. Now, that when I am executing the client, am getting the following error:


F:\EJBProject\advice>java -classpath AdviceAppClient.jar;. AdviceClient
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:

        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at AdviceClient.go(AdviceClient.java:26)
        at AdviceClient.main(AdviceClient.java:11)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
```

Please help. I am stuck up badly here. I wanted to sit for the OCBCD exam!

Regards,
Shouvanik

Comment: Your error suggest that the RMI server you are trying to connect does not exist. What port is your RMI server listening at ? What j2ee server are you using ? Is that sun j2ee server ?

Comment: RMI port is 1050 and it is running. i am using j2ee 1.3 RI and jdk1.4.

Comment: check all these required libs and instructions while connecting to rmi server from a standalone java program. It has also sample program too. >> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19644-01/817-5050/dcacc.html#wp1016235

Comment: Still it did not help. If this example was running for you, please share the steps. That would be more helpful.

Comment: I use websphere and tomcat. Don't use sun j2ee server. But I will test your code in sun if I find time.

Comment: thanks Ravi..but since I am new to EJB , I prefer using RI. all the new app servers are built on top of Sun j2ee server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved.

If you hit a roadblock while running the first EJB example simply follow these steps
to run the first example of HeadFirst EJB.

Softwares
1. j2sdk1.4.1 - jdk
2. j2sdkee1.3.1 - j2ee RI
3. CMD (command prompt)

Compile all the classes using c:\j2sdkee1.3.1\lib\j2ee.jar library.
Now, create a App and deploy EJB inside RI. download the application client as shown in the book.

Now, comes the tricky part.

Compile client class using the following jars

javac -classpath AdviceAppClient.jar;c:\j2sdkee1.3.1\lib\j2ee.jar AdviceClient.java

Next, run the client as follows

java -cp AdviceAppClient.jar;c:\j2sdkee1.3.1\lib\j2ee.jar;c:\j2sdk1.4.1\jre\lib\rt.jar;. AdviceClient